# .NET Core how to resolve dependency that was setup in ConfigureServices explicitly?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, azure-functions

I am using ConfigureServices() in an Azure Function and calling AddSingleton() to set up dependencies.
This works great when I am not explicitly instantiating an object, like when it's a class member.
But how do I take advantage of this DI paradigm when I explicitly instantiate a class?

Example:

```
//my class
public class SomeClass
{
    void DoStuff(){}
}

//inside Program.cs
.ConfigureServices(s) =>
{
   s.AddSingleton<SomeClass>();
}

//anywhere in my project, I now have a DI'd SomeClass by simply putting it in the constructor
public class SomeOtherClass
{
   SomeClass mySingletonInstance;
   
   public SomeOtherClass(SomeClass inst)
   {
      mySingletonInstance=inst;
   }
   
   
   void UseTheStuff()
   {
      //this works great
      mySingletonInstance.DoStuff();
   }
}

//somewhere else in my code, I need a SomeClass instance, but it complains that I dont have a parameterless constructor. Not sure how to move forward?
public class SomeThirdPlace
{
    void TryDoAThing()
    {
        //this gives an error because I have no paramless ctor
        //how can I resolve that singleton I setup in my ConfigureServices?
        SomeOtherClass sc = new SomeOtherClass();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the guideline to [dependency injection in Azure functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection), you can just add a constructor to `SomeThirdPlace` which takes an argument of type `SomeOtherClass`.

This way, whenever an instance of `SomeThirdPlace` is requested, it will automatically be resolved to use the objects that you injected.